# useEffect срабатывает дважды

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Парни, вопрос такой, есть страница, в коде сидит useEffect с пустым массивом зависимостей. Внутри useEffect функция, которая бегает за данными и сохраняет их в стейт.
Проблема вот в чем, если я нахожусь на этой странице и перезагружаю ее, функция бегает за данными 1 раз, и все ок. Но если я зайду на эту страницу с предыдущей(через клик) , то функция носится за данными 2 раза, и получается в 2 раза больше запросов.

```
useEffect: 
 useEffect(() => {fetchData()}, [id])

fetchData:
    const fetchData = async () => {

    try {
       await setLoad(true)
       await dispatch(setSelectedSectionThunk(id))
    } catch (err) {
       console.log(err)
       await dispatch(SET_ERROR())
    } finally {
       await setLoad(false)
    }
}
```

Внутри функции setSelectedSectionThunk запрос и запись в стейт

Comment: Показали бы код

Comment: Поправил, готово

Comment: ну каждый раз как у вас будет изменяться ID то при новом рендеринге будет отрабатывать useEffect.